# Instagram api returns HTTP status 200 but response contains empty data array

Tags: instagram

My curl request to get users id is not returning any data.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=xxxxx&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Here is the result i am getting:
{"data": [], "meta": {"code": 200}}

Any thought where there might be any issue?

Thanks,
Mojgan

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in Sandbox mode. In Sandbox mode you will only see your data and the users you approved to sandbox.

If you search your username in the API call  `q=`, you will see just your user details in the `data=[]` response.

Once you go live and have been approved for `public_content`, you will see all the user results.

Read more about Sandbox mode here:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

> Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from
>   each sandbox user
>
> Apps in sandbox are restricted to 10 users
>
> Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from
>   each of those users

Answer (score 1):

Instagram changed their API settings and ruined so many app across the web this morning. They are switching to FB https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/

To use the new Instagram API features, users will need to have a business profile and will be required to use a Facebook Login when granting access to third party tools.

Comment: not true, the old APIs still work, the Graph API is for businesses to manage their posts and moderate comments. They are limiting access to new developers accessing the old APIs starting Oct 1st, but it is still working for those who have been approved